# PHP database error handling in try-catch block using PDO connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, exception, try-catch

I am working on an exercise that involves using a try-catch block to throw Exceptions if database rows don't exist.  Here's an example of a `read()` function:

```
class Manager {
    private $desc;
    private $id;
    private $newDesc;
    public function read($id) {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=database', 'root', '');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM table where `id` = :id_val";
            $query = $db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bindParam(":id_val", $id);
            $query->execute();
            $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Could not return specified row! <br />";
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($results);
        echo "</pre>";
   }
}
```

Outside the class I run:

```
$manager = new Manager();
$manager->read(44); // this is an id that IS NOT an existing record
```

My browser shows `Array()` 
Am I placing the wrong statements into the try-catch, or is it something else altogether?

Comment: having an empty result set will not be catched, just handle it separately

Comment: "Exceptions if database rows don't exist" -- You would have to throw your own exception because that doesn't throw one by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal behaviour, "try catch" statements catches errors, exceptions... No record given id is not an error. If you want to check there is record or not you can count your result set with

```
count($results);
```

If this count is bigger than 0, it exists.